# sql query push certain records to top

Tags: sql

Im looping through forum topics with a mySQL query, but id like records with the field `sticky` being `1` to always be pushed to the top, or first, then it looping through the rest.

How could I do this?

At the moment they are ordered like `ORDER BY last_post DESC` (`last_post` being a datetime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `ORDER BY sticky DESC, last_post DESC` should work.